# Is (12!)*(9!)*(16!) too many configurations for a brute force solution?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I am trying to optimise a system. Its a network. I will optimise it by swapping the positions of nodes. There are three regions where I can swap nodes (so that nodes can only be swapped with nodes in the same region). The region's have sizes of 12,  9, and 16. As far as I know,  this means that I have (12!)*(9!)*(16!) possible configurations.
My question then is, do I have too many possible solutions to just run through solutions on say, a Python program that just checks configurations against some cost function. My cost function is just summations and multiplications.

Comment: Compute the log, in base 2, of that number. This will tell you how many bits it contains. You'll see it is much larger than the largest integer that can be natively represented on your computer (a 64 bit _double_ type).

Comment: That's $3.64\times 10^{27}$...very, very big.

Comment: Yes it is too many

Answer (score 4):

In 2013, the world's fastest supercomputer was performing 33 quadrillion operations per second, or $3.3\times 10^{13}$.

$12!9!16!$ is just a little over $3.3 \times 10^{27}$.

That means that, assuming each configuration only required a single operation, it would take over $10^{14}$ seconds to complete all configurations, over 3 million years.

So, unless you're VERY patient, you might want to find a way to reduce that number.

Comment: And they say there's not such thing as a dumb question